# Spree Commerce API: Users and Addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

An object conspicuously missing from [the Spree Commerce API docs](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/) is any sort of Customer or User.  Spree's Github page does sneakily contain [a User object controller](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/api/app/controllers/spree/api/users_controller.rb), though, and it does work. For example doing a GET to {{your spree url}}/api/users will spit out a JSON list of users, their emails and creation dates.

But, it's not clear how (or if) User Addressess can be set. The API does have [an Addresses endpoint](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/addresses.html), but no methods to create new ones or associate them with anything. [Addresses can be associated with Checkouts](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/checkouts.html#address), but I don't see any way to associate them with Users.  Any ideas?

Comment: hopefully u found a clean solution for that, because i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

spree_auth_devise may be a good starting point:
https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise

Comment: I'm not asking how to build an authentication system. I want to know how to use the Spree Commerce API to add shipping and billing addresses to their existing user object.

Answer (score 0):

You can take latest code using github url like below

```
gem 'spree', '~> 4.1', :git => "https://github.com/spree/spree.git", :branch => "master"
```

Then you will be able to call

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/v2/storefront/account/addresses' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer your-token'
```